# Animation(topup and top down) not smooth

Tags: android, animation

I am having a `LinearLayout` on top of `ListView`. When I scroll list down, I want the `LinearLayout` to disappear with top up animation giving room to list. Also, when I scroll list up, I want the `LinearLayout` to appear again with top down animation.

Here is the code I am using, but animation is not smooth:

xml-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/choicelayout"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
.
.
.
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/choicelayout"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

fragment

```
    topup = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), R.anim.top_up);
    topdown=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),R.anim.top_down);

    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (mLastFirstVisibleItem < firstVisibleItem) {
                if(mChoiceLayout.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
                    mChoiceLayout.startAnimation(topup);
                    mChoiceLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            if (mLastFirstVisibleItem > firstVisibleItem) {
                if(mChoiceLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
                    mChoiceLayout.startAnimation(topdown);
                    mChoiceLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;

        }
    });
```

topup animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%" android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

topdown animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [Property Animation API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) instead of the really old AnimationUtils.

It results in really smooth animations, however it's only available from Android level 11.

If you'd need it for lower versions there's a library for it called [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

Comment: Yeah my min sdk version is more than 1..Glad if u can help me wid code as i am fresher

Comment: Sorry, this page is not for getting tutorials, check my link provided in my answer (click [Property Animation API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)), there you should find every information you need. Also if my answer helped you, you could accept it.